# Functionally constrained optimization using fmincon (in Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, optimization, functional-programming, constraints

I want to set a constraint for every x value, 0<=f(x,vctr)<=100. The result is:

> ??? Undefined function or variable 'x' due to functional constraint "cnstrnt".

Although it is a variable, `fmincon` asks for a value of `x` in `cnstrnt`. `x` represents multiple variables. `b`, `k`, and `vctr` (vector of constants) are constants. What is the correct way of coding the constraint?

```
function [ h ] = f(x,vctr)

g=@(x) (vctr(1,6).*x.^5+vctr(1,5).*x.^4+vctr(1,4).*x.^3+ ...
vctr(1,3).*x.^2+vctr(1,2).*x.^1+vctr(1,1));
h=fzero( @(x)(g(x)-y),0);
end

function [ cc,ceq ] = cnstrnt(x,b,vctr)

for k=1:length(b)*2

       cc(k)=f(x(k),vctr)-100;
       cc(k+1)=-f(x(k),vctr);
end

ceq=[];

end


[result,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,LAMBDA,GRAD,HESSIAN]= fmincon(@(x)obj(x,b,c,L,vctr) ,x0,A,B,Aeq,beq,[],ub,cnstrnt(x,b,vctr),opts);

??? Undefined function or variable 'x'.
```

Comment: What is `f` in your function `cnstrnt`? Where is it defined?

Comment: f is a polynomial function (but linear given x) which is dependet on variable x and constants vctr. Every value of x is evaluated w.r.t function f to match the specified condition.

Comment: If you're showing `cnstrnt` in it's entirety, then I don't see how the function has access to `f`. Where is `f` defined?

Comment: The function f is defined in an other m-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable must be declared with `@(x)` as  `@(x)cnstrnt(x,b,vctr)`. Then `fmincon` can recognize the variables and differentiate from the constants.

```
[result,FVAL,EXITFLAG,OUTPUT,LAMBDA,GRAD,HESSIAN]= fmincon(@(x)obj(x,b,c,L,vctr) ,x0,A,B,Aeq,beq,[],ub,@(x)cnstrnt(x,b,vctr),opts);
```

Comment: Just add it but do not contribute !